# WhiteSpaces Not allowed in Cell Editor primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, whitespace

i am using primefaces
i cannot insert whitespace when using P:celleditor that contain facet inputtext.

```
<p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{messages.lb_offr_appl}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputTextarea id="applicabilityinput" value="#{prest.applicability}" style="width:100%"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{prest.applicability}" id="applicabilityoutput" />
                                </f:facet>

                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
```

any advice what to do to be able to insert strings with white spaces like "str1 str2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue in a *DataTable* when using *rowEditor* and *draggableRows=true* at the same time. If I remove *draggableRows=true* on my table then the whitespaces are accepted in the cellEditor.

I manage to make cellEditors(accepting whitespaces) and drag&drop work at he same time by using the [Cell Editing with Click and RightClick](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) and *draggableRows=true*.

My guess is that there is some JS/JQuery conflict/error behind it but couldn't figure it out yet. If someone has a real clue of why the whitespaces are not accepted sometime in cellEditor I'm interested as well.

I also read somewhere that when one enable a feature of DataTable is could break another one...

Comment: I am not using draggableRows=true,I've searched alot and find that its bug in primefaces 6.0 but i can't change my version do anyone have a solution for this issue HOW TO ADD SPACES WHEN HIT SPACE BAR IN INPUT TEXT THAT EXIST INSIDE P:CELL EDITOR ?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, do you use contextual menu on your table? If I remove the contextual menu then white spaces work... hope it helps a bit

Comment: You could maybe catch the enter key event to add a white space using javascript but it sounds way too complicated for such a basic feature, I wouldn't go that way.
FYI I give a try to the last release of Primefaces and I still have the same issue.